# C# Datatable to IList conversion

Tags: c#

I am using the below code to convert `Dataset` to `IList`. 
Is there a better way to write the code below:

```
IList lst = new List<object>();
var tbl = dsList.Tables[0];
foreach (DataRow dr in tbl.Rows)
{
   lst.Add(dr.ItemArray);
}
```

Comment: There is always is better way to do anything. But you need to be more specific. Should the desired code be more elegant? Or is it about performance?

Comment: It is more about the performance and i am using .NET 4.0

Comment: Then there is no "better" way.

Comment: Does using LINQ     IList<object> lst = dsList.Tables[0].Rows.Select(x => x.ItemArray).ToList() have a preformance hit

Comment: No. It will do all that you have done. Even more so, using linq is preferred if you will use methods such as First(), or Last(), etc, because it will not enumerate the whole collection, rather it will just get the requested element, which is more performant.

Comment: But it doesn't work (at least for me) it says 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension methods...  And i am using .NET 4.5

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
using System.Linq;


    IList<object> lst = dsList.Tables[0].Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(x => x.ItemArray).ToList();
```

Simply using System.Link's [Select()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx) method on the `Rows` collection of the `table`. This is an extension method which can be called on any `IEnumerable<T>` (means also on any object which implements that interface directly or through inheritance).

If you don't have an `IEnumerable<T>` to query, rather a simple `IEnumerable` (non generic), you can use a trick of calling [.OfType()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb360913(v=vs.100).aspx) on it, which returns the generic instance.

If you want to flatten out an enumerable, you can use [SelectMany()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany(v=vs.100).aspx).

If you're stuck on a pre-linq .NET, you must have a loop.

Comment: Give some information about what you are doing here

Comment: This is .NET3.5+ if you're like me, stuck in a NET2.0 environment you have to use your for loop. Read more about LINQ here : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397933.aspx

Comment: Yes, if you're stuck on .NET < 3.5 you should say so in the question.

Comment: Using .NET 4.0.  dsList.Tables[0].Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(x => x.ItemArray).ToList(); worked fine but does this have a performance hit than loopng?

Comment: To not repeat myself, please see my comment below the original question.

Comment: I don't know why but it actually didn't work for me... 'System.Data.DataRowCollection' does not contain a definition for 'Select' and no extension methods... etc  Version of .Net framework is 4.5

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see, no there is no way to improve your code.  The method you are currently using is already the best possible solution.

Comment: The List should contain the `.ItemArray`s of the DataRows.

Comment: Then you need to iterate through it with foreach loop or use LINQ a can't really see what else you can do here